# AngularJS for loop not waiting for modifications to $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I've been wracking my brain over this for a few days, so I figured it's time to finally ask somebody who actually knows what they're doing.  ;)

I'm building an AngularJS app and getting an odd behavior when I'm iterating through a couple of my for loops.  I'm trying to find the 'best' option to add to a list given a few possibilities, and so here's my general process for how I'd like to get it done:

**The Idea:**
1) add each possibility to the desination list, say $scope.list1
2) calculate the 'score' based on the state of the lists
3) remove the possibility from $scope.list1
4) repeat for all possibilities.

Here's the basic idea of what I'm running in my controller:

```
$scope.getSuggestions = function(){
   //for each possibility to consider:      
   for(var i = 0; i < possibilities.length; i++){
      //add the possibility to the scope as per usual
      $scope.list1.push(possibilities[i]);

      //calculate the score given the state of the scope
      $scope.calculateScore();

      //save the score in a new object on the scope
      $scope.results.push({"option": possibilities[i],
                           "score": $scope.score
      });

      //remove the possibility to reset the scope back to its original state
      $scope.list1.pop();
   }
};
```

**The Problem:**
It seems as if my for loop is actually moving on to further iterations before the code has finished executing.  My $scope.calculateScore() function may take a bit of time to run, and it seems like it's being ignored by the for loop. I'm not doing anything obviously asynchronous in that function; it's mostly other for loops based on the state of the $scope and some math to get a 'score'.

**My question:**
Why does Angular think it's okay to continue blazing through a for loop when the code inside hasn't finished executing?  I see how it could make sense in certain cases, but in this one it's vital that everything happens in order, after the previous functions have finished.  Do you all have any suggestions on how to make this work?

Note:  You can see the code in its entirety by viewing the source at http://www.PlatTheLeague.com

The actual code for calculateScore() is in scripts/controllers/teamBuilderCtrl.js, where the function is called $scope.populateGamePredictions().  My initial tries at the suggestions are in the same file, called $scope.getChampSuggestions.  To see the problem, drag an item from the list on the left to the box that says 'Their Top' and then click on the 'Champion Suggestions' tab.  That tab *should* be populated with the results of $scope.results listed above in the pseudo-code, but it seems that the teamScore on my scope object isn't being set properly.

Cheers!

Comment: angular is build on js so assuming there is nothing async in your code, there's no way for angular to "blaze through". JS will block the thread until the functions return. If you do some logging you could prove it to yourself or confirm something wonky is going on.

Comment: What does calculateScore() do? Does it make an Ajax call by any chance?

Comment: calculateScore() doesn't have any ajax or http calls or anything like that.  That's why I'm confused by this... I wonder if creating some logging isn't just my best option.  I've never done it before, but that doesn't mean it isn't still a good idea.  ;)

Comment: It doesn't need to be ajax to be async. Please provide us the code for calaculateScore

Comment: I can confirm that this code will complete without "blazing through" given that calculateScore is sync...

Comment: If `calculateScore` definitely doesn't do anything asynchronous, for example using `$timeout` or `$http`, then I suspect your method for determining that it's "moving on to further iterations" might not be accurate. Can you explain how you did this? Posting a Plunker of your code (or a version of your code) showing the problem will answer a lot of questions.

Comment: @MichalCharemza I've edited the OP with a link to the source code.  (I'm embarrassed by the state of my code, but it works for an early prototype).  Let me know if there is anything else I can help with, and thanks for taking time to check this out!

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I think there is too much going on in that page + in the source in order to realistically help. I suspect to get help on the issue a working (or rather, non-working!) _very_ stripped down Plunker, and posting the stripped down code here, demonstrating that it behaves as you says it does, will make it possible for your question, about blazing through, to be answered.

Comment: I built a simplified plunker which proved to me that the code was executing as I believed it should be, and found an issue with my data model that was causing calculateScore() to fail without any obvious errors.  I've resolved the issue and posted my answer below.  Thanks for all of your time thinking about this!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some logics that change the internal states of `$scope` from outside of AngularJS, maybe from some kinds of events from DOM, ajax callbacks, setTimeout ... In that case, `$apply` method can help. You can have more references of `$apply` from here: [https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, The above idea works in the typical synchronous manner, as I've proved to myself in this plunker:   http://plnkr.co/edit/9spVbf5JWx9Hnq53sHSV?p=preview

My issue arose from the fact that the data model being worked on by my calculateScore() function was not formatted exactly how I thought it would be (my own fault, thanks to the semi-complicated nature of the app...) which meant that the scores weren't being updated properly in the first place, though the code was running as expected.